# How to resolve "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" errors from iCal/CalDAV server after upgrade to Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard, opendirectory, ical, caldav

We recently upgraded our Open Directory Master & Replica to Mac OS X 10.6.4 Snow Leopard Server. We had a mismatched server FQDN & LDAP Search Base/Kerberos Realm, so we exported all users & groups, created the new Open Directory Master w/matching FQDN & Search Base/Realm, reimported users & groups, and re-bound all servers & workstations to the new OD Master.

At the same time as all of this, we upgraded our iCal/CalDAV server to Mac OS X 10.6.4 Snow Leopard Server. Ever since doing so, we've seen the following issues with our iCal/CalDAV server and iCal clients on both Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard & Mac OS X 10.6:

- If a user attempts to move or delete an event (single or repeating) that was created prior to the upgrade to 10.6 Server, they get the following error:

  > Access to "blah" in "blah" in account "blah" is not permitted.
  >
  > The server responded:
  >   "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" to operation CalDAVWriteEntityQueueableOperation.
- New users added to the directory get the following error when attempting to add their account to in iCal's preferences:

  > The user "blah" has no configured pricipals.
  >
  > Confirm with your network administrator that your account has at least one CalDAV principal configured.

Interestingly, we've since discovered that users seem to be able to delete individual events from an old repeating event without error, but that's a massive amount of work to get rid of a repeating event.

I will note that we have *not* yet added an SRV record in DNS as instructed on page 19 of iCal_Server_Admin_v10.6.pdf.

**Further Investigation:**

In this particular case, a user is attempting to decline repeating events created prior to the upgrade to Snow Leopard Server. Granting the user full write access with `sudo calendarserver_manage_principals --add-write-proxy users:user1 users:user2` (which did work) doesn't allow deletion of the events. Still get the usual error:

```
Access to "blah blah" in "blah blah" in account "blah blah" is not permitted.

The server responded:
"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
to operation CalDAVWriteEntityQueueableOperation.
```

The error that shows up in /var/log/caldavd/error.log on the iCal Server when attempting to delete one of the events is:

```
2011-03-17 15:14:30-0400 [-] [caldav-8009] [PooledMemCacheProtocol,client] [twistedcaldav.extensions#info] PUT /calendars/__uids__/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/calendar/XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.ics HTTP/1.1 2011-03-17 15:14:30-0400 [-] [caldav-8009] [PooledMemCacheProtocol,client] [twistedcaldav.scheduling.implicit#error] Cannot change ORGANIZER: UID:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

And the error in /var/log/system.log on the client is:

```
Mar 17 15:14:30 192-168-21-169-dhcp iCal[33509]: CalDAV CalDAVWriteEntityQueueableOperation failed: status 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' request:\n\nBEGIN:VCALENDAR^M\nVERSION:2.0^M\nPRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iCal 3.0//EN^M\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN^M\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE^M\nTZID:US/Eastern^M\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT^M\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0500^M\nTZOFFSETTO:-0400^M\nDTSTART:20070311T020000^M\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU^M\nTZNAME:EDT^M\nEND:DAYLIGHT^M\nBEGIN:STANDARD^M\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0400^M\nTZOFFSETTO:-0500^M\nDTSTART:20071104T020000^M\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU^M\nTZNAME:EST^M\nEND:STANDARD^M\nEND:VTIMEZONE^M\nBEGIN:VEVENT^M\nSEQUENCE:5^M\nDTSTART;TZID=US/Eastern:20090117T094500^M\nDTSTAMP:20081227T143043Z^M\nSUMMARY:blah blah^M\nATTENDEE;CN="First Last";CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:urn:uuid^M\n :XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX^M\nATTENDEE;CN="First Last";CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:user@d^M\n omain.tld^M\nEXDATE;TZID=US/Eastern:20110319T094500^M\nDTEND;TZID=US/Eastern:20090117T183000^M\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1^M\nTRANSP:OPAQUE^M\nUID:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX^M\nORGANIZER;CN="First Last":mailto:user@domain.tld^M\nX-WR-ITIPSTATUSML:UNCLEAN^M\nCREATED:20110317T191348Z^M\nEND:VEVENT^M\nEND:VCALENDAR^M\n\n\n... response:\nHTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden^M\nDate: Thu, 17 Mar 2011 19:14:30 GMT^M\nDav: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-auto-schedule, calendar-availability, inbox-availability, calendar-proxy, calendarserver-private-events, calendarserver-private-comments, calendarserver-principal-property-search^M\nContent-Type: text/xml^M\nContent-Length: 134^M\nServer: Twisted/8.2.0 TwistedWeb/8.2.0 TwistedCalDAV/2.5 (iCal Server v12.56.21)^M\n^M\n<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><error xmlns='DAV:'>^M\n  <valid-attendee-change xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'/>^M\n</error>
```

One thing I have noticed, and I'm not sure if this has any real effect is that in many of these pre-Snow Leopard Server migration events, the ORGANIZER is specified like the following:

```
ORGANIZER;CN=First Last:mailto:user@domain.tld
```

But newer ones are more like one of the two following:

```
ORGANIZER;CN=First Last;EMAIL=user@domain.tld;SCHEDULE-STATUS=1

ORGANIZER;CN=First Last;EMAIL=user@domain.tld:urn:uuid:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

iCal_Server_Admin_v10.6.pdf notes that the ".db.sqlite" files are completely disposable, they're merely a performance cache and are re-built on the fly, so are safe to delete. I did delete the one for the organizer's calendars and it took longer to process the attempted event delete while it rebuilt the database, but still errored out in the end.

FWIW the error is thrown by this code:

https://trac.calendarserver.org/browser/CalendarServer/trunk/twistedcaldav/scheduling/implicit.py

Any further suggestions? I see lots of questions about this in my Google searches, but not solutions and this is a widespread problem on our iCal Server. Now, we mostly try to get users to ignore them (hence the amount of time this question has been open), but every now and then I dig in deeper trying to find the culprit and/or solution.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nope, still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

As for me the problem occured when using iCal with Google Calendar when I choosed my @gmail.com address instead of the @googlemail.com address. After removing the calendar from iCal and adding it again with ...@googlemail.com everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problems and resolved it by fixing the owner of the Calendar data store as described on p.42 of the iCal Server Admin 10.6.  I issued the following at the Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R _calendar:_calendar /Library/CalendarServer/Documents
```

My "Documents" folder had the correct permissions, but some files or folders a few directories down had "root" as the owner, so above command fixed it and no more users experienced errors.

You may have to change permissions as well with chmod, but in my case they were fine.